# MVC BeginForm - Return three different ajax text strings from controller

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I need to send 3 variables (viewbags) to the view from the controller when data is submitted in beginform. At the moment I can only get 1 variable to post back due to the AJAX function below.

JQUERY/AJAX

```
   function autosubmit() {


        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: this.action,
            data: $('form').serialize(),
           success: function (result) {
                    $('#one').html(result); //ViewBag.one
                    $('#two').html(result); //ViewBag.two
                    $('#three').html(result); //ViewBag.three
                                     }

        });


    }
```

FORM:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
//form data automatically submits to controller
}


<div id="one">ajax data</div>
<div id="two">ajax data</div>
<div id="three">ajax data</div>
```

CONTROLLER

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(model stuff)
        {
         ViewBag.one = stuff.data1;
         ViewBag.two = stuff.data2;
         ViewBag.three = stuff.data3;
         Return(ViewBag.one, ViewBag.two,ViewBag.three)
         }
```

Answer (score 7):

Forget about ViewBag/ViewData. It's as if it never existed.

Use JSON:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(model stuff)
{
    var data = new 
    { 
        data1 = stuff.data1, 
        data2 = stuff.data2, 
        data3 = stuff.data3 
    };
    return Json(data);
}
```

and then consume:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: this.action,
    data: $('form').serialize(),
    success: function (result) {
        $('#one').html(result.data1);
        $('#two').html(result.data2);
        $('#three').html(result.data3);
    }
});
```